# Drupal Notifications - Users receiving duplicate emails

Tags: drupal, email, notifications, drupal-5

We are using Drupal (5.x) Notifications module.

Our users are receiving duplicate emails (related to forum posts)

First email has this subject line: "Your Daily xyz Discussion Digest"
Second email has this subject line: "xyz subscription update for UserABC"

Content is somewhat similar. (formatting is different).

Tried to google for solution. No luck yet.

Any one seen this issue before?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds like message duping:

> **Deduping**
>
> There may be also more than one
>   subscription producing multiple
>   notifications for the same event. I.e.
>   if you are subscribed to 'story
>   updates' and subscribed to the
>   specific thready 'my story 1', then
>   updating 'my story 1' will actually
>   produce two notifications, one for
>   each subscription. These go through
>   some deduping process before being
>   sent out, merging notifications for
>   the same event into one notification.
>   However, this can be done if (and only
>   if) both subscriptions are using the
>   same sending method and the same
>   sending interval. Otherwise you'll be
>   getting two or more different
>   notifications for the same event.

see http://drupal.org/node/318577